# How to fix 'Worker failed to boot'?

Tags: python, gunicorn

I try to install on my VPS this Pool Script:
https://github.com/jamescoxon/rai_quarry_pool

I did the first steps but then I have problem from:

```
git clone https://github.com/jamescoxon/rai_quarry_pool.git
Edit app.py and submit.py and add the address you want the faucet to pay to
Open screen
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app
Detach the screen using Ctrl-A-D
```

gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 app:app

give me this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in  import_app
import(module)
ImportError: No module named 'app'
[2017-05-04 08:15:42 +0000] [5726] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 5726)
[2017-05-04 08:15:42 +0000] [5723] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2017-05-04 08:15:42 +0000] [5723] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

any ideas please?

I also read in other posts but cant get it fixed.

I can record youtube video step step if its help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cloning the git repo get inside the folder `rai_quarry_pool` and run that command. I guess you guys are trying to execute the command from somewhere else.

Comment: with sudo su cd /root/rai_quarry_pool yes? i try before it didnt work, but I try now again and work hahah, thank you:)